# How to resize attribute boxes in Visio attributes

Tags: visio, database-diagram

This is a very simply request, but I cannot locate the solution. I have Visio 2016 and the layout within Visio is using the Crows foot database notation, with Entities and Attributes within. However, it appears I cannot change the thickness of a text box and therefore the result is a very long Entity:

[image]

There are no leading or trailing blanks, nor is the text very large or and the container is not locked.

How can I change the shape of these attribute boxes?

Comment: I think it might be useful to attach the actual Visio file (just a minimal version will do). P.S. I'm sure you are aware that simple requests very rarely are!

Comment: This is probably better suited for SU than SO, so I've flagged it as such.
Have you checked the shapesheet? It is possible that the value is forced in there. And have you tried the developer-protection options? Is this a part of a container or is the shape a "Subshape" of another shape?

Comment: Ok, I just checked, the height of the Shape is guarded with `=GUARD(MAX(9 mm,TEXTHEIGHT(TheText,TxtWidth),Sheet.XXXX!TxtHeight))`, you can set a fixed value there or check what is causing the wrong size. The XXXX Shape is the Shape on the far right inside the shape-group.